# Get selected item to populate textboxes in ionic 2 and angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm pulling a list of items and then populate it into a drop down. What i want to achieve is when i select a product, its price should be populated in the quantity textbox.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Item</ion-label>
  <ion-select (ionChange)="getProduct()" [(ngModel)]="product">
    <ion-option [value]="item.product" *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.product}}</ion-option>

  </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Available</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="quantity"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

JS

```
  items:any;
  product:any;
  available:any;
  quantity:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

    this.items=[

      {
          "product": "Ideal Milk",
          "quantity": '5'
      },
      {
        "product": "Indome",
        "quantity": '1'
      },
      {
          "product": "Corn Flakes",
          "quantity": '20'
      },
      {
        "product": "Digestive Biscuit",
        "quantity": '12'
      }
  ]
  }


  getProduct(){

  }

}
```

i'm trying to write a function `getProduct()` which will check for the product selected and the populate in it in the quantity textbox, thats what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ion-select` is binded to `product` and `ion-input` to `quantity` so all you need to do is update `quantity` when `ion-select` is changed.

1) Just renamed `getProduct()` to `onSelectValueChange()` to be more clear.

2) When product changes `onSelectValueChange` is fired. Update `this.quantity` inside `onSelectChange()`. New value of `quantity` should  automatically reflect `ion-input`.

`.html`

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Item</ion-label>
  <ion-select (ionChange)="getProduct()" [(ngModel)]="product">
    <ion-option [value]="item.product" *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.product}}</ion-option>

  </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Available</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="quantity"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

`.ts`

```
 items:any;
  product:any;
  available:any;
  quantity:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

    this.items=[

      {
          "product": "Ideal Milk",
          "quantity": '5'
      },
      {
        "product": "Indome",
        "quantity": '1'
      },
      {
          "product": "Corn Flakes",
          "quantity": '20'
      },
      {
        "product": "Digestive Biscuit",
        "quantity": '12'
      }
  ]
  }


  onSelectValueChange(){
      this.quantity = this.items.find((element)=>element.product=== this.product).quantity
  }

}
```